# Simple octree traversal: How to get the intersection points with AABB

Tags: java, intersection, raytracing, bounding-box, octree

This is my first question here on stackoverflow, so i hope i got all things right. For an java project i need to use an octree for raytracing. I already created an simple octree (without neighbour information or something) and sorted the triangles of the object meshs into the AABB's of the octree. Now I would like to make an easy traversation through the tree for every ray. (it should be really easy because the time to finish this project is very short). The basic algorithmn is the following:

1. Start with the first node
2. if this node is hit, remember the place of the intersection in a sorted list
3. if this node has children check if the child boxes are hit and write every intersection point in a sorted list
4. start with the child box with the nearest intersection point
5. if this box has children too see 4)
6. if a node doesn't have any childs check every triangle in this
   box against the ray
7. if a triangle is hit get the color of triangle (with shading and
   everything) and draw it on the screen

Unfortunately my current implementation seems to have a "bug" in the intersection calculation (ray vs ABBB). I check if any side of the AABB is hit and remember the clostest ip (smallest distance from ray origin).

Here is the Code for this function in my BoundingBox Class:

```
public HitResult intersects6(Ray ray) {
    double t;
    Vec3d ip = new Vec3d();
    HitResult finalHitResult = null;

    // front xy
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.z) > Helper.EPSYLON) {
        t = (vmax.z - ray.origin.z) / ray.direction.z;

        ip.x = ray.origin.x + t * ray.direction.x;
        ip.y = ray.origin.y + t * ray.direction.y;
        ip.z = vmax.z;


        if ((ip.x >= vmin.x) && (ip.x <= vmax.x) && (ip.y >= vmin.y) && (ip.y <= vmax.y)) {
            // here is an intersection
            double distance = Vec3d.distance(ray.origin, ip);
            finalHitResult = new HitResult(ip, distance);
        }

    }
    // back xy
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.z) > Helper.EPSYLON) {
        t = (vmin.z + ray.origin.z) / -ray.direction.z;

        ip.x = ray.origin.x + t * ray.direction.x;
        ip.y = ray.origin.y + t * ray.direction.y;
        ip.z = vmin.z;

        if ((ip.x >= vmin.x) && (ip.x <= vmax.x) && (ip.y >= vmin.y) && (ip.y <= vmax.y)) {
            double distance = Vec3d.distance(ray.origin, ip);
            if (finalHitResult!= null) {
                if(distance < finalHitResult.distance)
                    finalHitResult.distance = distance;
                    finalHitResult.point = ip; 
            }
            else 
                finalHitResult = new HitResult(ip, distance);

        }

    }
    // Side Right
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.x) > Helper.EPSYLON) {
        t = (vmax.x - ray.origin.x) / ray.direction.x;

        ip.y = ray.origin.y + t * ray.direction.y;
        ip.z = ray.origin.z + t * ray.direction.z;
        ip.x = vmax.x;

        if ((ip.y >= vmin.y) && (ip.y <= vmax.y) && (ip.z >= vmin.z) && (ip.z <= vmax.z)) {
            double distance = Vec3d.distance(ray.origin, ip);
            if (finalHitResult!= null) {
                if(distance < finalHitResult.distance)
                    finalHitResult.distance = distance;
                    finalHitResult.point = ip; 
            }
            else 
                finalHitResult = new HitResult(ip, distance);
        }
    }
    // Side Left
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.x) > Helper.EPSYLON) {
        t = (vmin.x + ray.origin.x) / -ray.direction.x;

        ip.y = ray.origin.y + t * ray.direction.y;
        ip.z = ray.origin.z + t * ray.direction.z;
        ip.x = vmin.x;

        if ((ip.y >= vmin.y) && (ip.y <= vmax.y) && (ip.z >= vmin.z) && (ip.z <= vmax.z)) {
            double distance = Vec3d.distance(ray.origin, ip);
            if (finalHitResult!= null) {
                if(distance < finalHitResult.distance)
                    finalHitResult.distance = distance;
                    finalHitResult.point = ip; 
            }
            else 
                finalHitResult = new HitResult(ip, distance);
        }
    }
    // Top
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.y) > Helper.EPSYLON) {
        t = (vmax.y - ray.origin.y) / ray.direction.y;

        ip.x = ray.origin.x + t * ray.direction.x;
        ip.z = ray.origin.z + t * ray.direction.z;
        ip.y = vmax.y;

        if ((ip.x >= vmin.x) && (ip.x <= vmax.x) && (ip.z >= vmin.z) && (ip.z <= vmax.z)) {
            double distance = Vec3d.distance(ray.origin, ip);
            if (finalHitResult!= null) {
                if(distance < finalHitResult.distance)
                    finalHitResult.distance = distance;
                    finalHitResult.point = ip; 
            }
            else 
                finalHitResult = new HitResult(ip, distance);
        }
    }
    // Bottom
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.y) > Helper.EPSYLON) {
        t = (vmin.y + ray.origin.y) / -ray.direction.y;

        ip.x = ray.origin.x + t * ray.direction.x;
        ip.z = ray.origin.z + t * ray.direction.z;
        ip.y = vmin.y;

        if ((ip.x >= vmin.x) && (ip.x <= vmax.x) && (ip.z >= vmin.z) && (ip.z <= vmax.z)) {
            double distance = Vec3d.distance(ray.origin, ip);
            if (finalHitResult!= null) {
                if(distance < finalHitResult.distance)
                    finalHitResult.distance = distance;
                    finalHitResult.point = ip; 
            }
            else 
                finalHitResult = new HitResult(ip, distance);
        }
    }

    return finalHitResult;
```

I guess this is not the best way to do it. In my first implementation i just used the t-values and compared them (to find the box i would like to visit next). But the problem was the same. Some intersections could not be found.

I also checked out the intersection method here: 
https://code.google.com/p/3d-workspace/source/browse/trunk/MathLibrary/Bounding/BoundingBox.cpp?r=17
but I can't see how to get the intersection point with this code (or even any t-value). Moreover i tested the slab method like descripted here:
http://tavianator.com/2011/05/fast-branchless-raybounding-box-intersections/
but this seems to also miss some intersections, i don't know why:

```
public double[] intersects3(Ray ray) {
    double Tnear = -1e30;
    double Tfar = 1e30;

    // First, check slab in X.
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.x) < 0.0) {
        // Ray is parallel to X, but starts outside. Fail.
        if (ray.origin.x < vmin.x || ray.origin.x > vmax.x) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        double Ta = ((vmin.x - ray.origin.x) / ray.direction.x), Tb = (vmax.x - ray.origin.x) / ray.direction.x;
        double T1 = Math.min(Ta, Tb);
        double T2 = Math.max(Ta, Tb);
        if (T1 > Tnear)
            Tnear = T1;
        if (T2 < Tfar)
            Tfar = T2;
        if (Tnear > Tfar)
            return null;
        if (Tfar < 0)
            return null;
    }

    // Then check slab in Y.
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.y) < 0.0) {
        // Ray is parallel to X, but starts outside. Fail.
        if (ray.origin.y < vmin.y || ray.origin.y > vmax.y) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        double Ta = (vmin.y - ray.origin.y) / ray.direction.y, Tb = (vmax.y - ray.origin.y) / ray.direction.y;
        double T1 = Math.min(Ta, Tb);
        double T2 = Math.max(Ta, Tb);
        if (T1 > Tnear)
            Tnear = T1;
        if (T2 < Tfar)
            Tfar = T2;
        if (Tnear > Tfar)
            return null;
        if (Tfar < 0)
            return null;
    }

    // Then check slab in Z.
    if (Math.abs(ray.direction.z) < 0.0) {
        // Ray is parallel to X, but starts outside. Fail.
        if (ray.origin.z < vmin.z || ray.origin.z > vmax.z) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        double Ta = (vmin.z - ray.origin.z) / ray.direction.z, Tb = (vmax.z - ray.origin.z) / ray.direction.z;
        double T1 = Math.min(Ta, Tb);
        double T2 = Math.max(Ta, Tb);
        if (T1 > Tnear)
            Tnear = T1;
        if (T2 < Tfar)
            Tfar = T2;
        if (Tnear > Tfar)
            return null;
        if (Tfar < 0)
            return null;
    }

    // If we have survived this far, the test passed.
    return new double[] { Tnear, Tfar };
}
```

Maybe I'm too stupid for raytracing at all.

But my actual question is:

Is it possible to use the t-values to compare which box has the closest intersection point ? And if yes, how can i get this t-values? Or what could i do to make the first code snipped work? (so far i would be happy with ANY working solution, even if this solution is very slow )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the statement `finalHitResult.point = ip;` in `if(distance < finalHitResult.distance)
                    finalHitResult.distance = distance;
                    finalHitResult.point = ip;` will always be executed, regardless of the `if` is true or false. You probably want to use brackets: `if(distance < finalHitResult.distance) {
                    finalHitResult.distance = distance;
                    finalHitResult.point = ip; }`

Comment: Why are you checking `if (Math.abs(ray.direction.x) < 0.0)`?  That is always false.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could be helpful:
http://chiranjivi.tripod.com/octrav.html

I've tried to implement the idea for a quadtree:
https://github.com/alexroat/quadtree-traversal